# Upload image to AWS bucket from remote server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a web application in PHP up and running. I want this app capable of uploading images to AWS s3 bucket. I am checking the documentation at AWS, but found at least three different documentations for this purpose. But still I am not clear, is possible that my web app hosted with a different hosting service will be able to upload files to AWS ?

If yes, which is the best option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to upload from outside of the AWS network.

Use the AWS PHP SDK at https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/

Then use the following code:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Common\Exception\MultipartUploadException;
use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
$keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1'
]);

// Prepare the upload parameters.
$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3, '/path/to/large/file.zip', [
    'bucket' => $bucket,
    'key'    => $keyname
]);

// Perform the upload.
try {
    $result = $uploader->upload();
    echo "Upload complete: {$result['ObjectURL']}" . PHP_EOL;
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Edit the bucket name, keyname, region and upload file name.

This is the multi-part upload style so you can upload huge files.